# Why 2^^1*^k does not work?

Tags: syntax, number-representation, input-forms

```
Table[2^^1*^k,{k,0,10}]
```

This gives an error, why is that?

Also this
    `BaseForm[2 ** 1*^ #, 16] & /@ Range[10]`

What is wrong here?

Comment: If you explain the output you expect, someone may be able to help you.

Comment: I didn’t think that the output where important, but i try to explain it in the comment to the answer of Mr.Wizard.

Comment: It doesn't work because `*^` is not an operator that joins two expressions.  It is part of the notation of numbers.  This situation is completely equivalent to asking why `Table[1k3, {k, 1, 4}]` does not work for producing the four numbers `{113,123,133,143}`.  Use an explicit multiplier as in `Table[num*base^k, {k, 0, 10}]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number entry form ***base*^^*digits*** is **only** valid for explicit [0-9] digits in the place of both *base* and *digits*.  You **cannot** write literal `b^^1001` and then attempt to replace `b` as `b^^1001` does not parse to this input form.

Likewise the number entry form ***m**^*exp*** is only valid for explicit [0-9] digits in the place of both *m* and *exp*.

The combination of these entry forms does work, but possibly not in the manner you intend.  (One must guess your intent.)  For example `2^^1001*^12` inputs 36864, because `1001*^12` is first converted to `1001000000000000` and then `2^^1001000000000000` becomes `36864`.

---

Responding to the comment below, if the combined behavior is what you want you could "force" this evaluation by assembling a String and then converting it to an Expression using [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html):

```
Table[ToExpression[ "2^^1*^" <> ToString[k] ], {k, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024}
> ```

This however makes one wonder why you would not simply write:

```
2^Range[0, 10]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024}
> ```

Or more generally:

```
Table[2^^1001 * 2^k, {k, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
> {9, 18, 36, 72, 144, 288, 576, 1152, 2304, 4608, 9216}
> ```

Equivalent to:

```
 Table[ToExpression["2^^1001*^" <> ToString[k]], {k, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Sorry if wasn’t clear with my problem. Yes that was exactly the behaviour that i was expecting. I’m working with a digital bus that takes 16bits in binary and only 1 bit at the time is on ( 1 ). So I want a list of 15 numbers `2^^1*^15, 2^^1*^14 ...` and convert it to hexadecimal.

Comment: @kafkarudo please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wizard, “It’s not the destination, but the journey, that matters”

Comment: @kafkarudo You're welcome. :-)